# database_cleaner without database.yml and multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, database-cleaner

I have a cucumber-tests of non-rails application.

I do not have database.yml in my project, and for some reasons dont want to have it (connection setting are stored in a bit different format).

I have several database models, defined like

```
class MyBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.some_extra_methods
  end 
end

class DatabaseA < MyBase
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection ($configA)
end

class DatabaseB < MyBase
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection ($configB)
end

# if i will not connect ActiveRecord::Base to something i get ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished errors 
# is there a better solution?
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection $configC;

class TableA < DatabaseA
  self.table_name =  :table_a
  self.primary_key = :id
end
#... and other tables

class TableB < DatabaseB
  self.table_name =  :table_b
  self.primary_key = :id
end
#... and other tables
```

Now to clean that databases i'm trying to use the following code.
I do not have database.yml so i'm just passing models.

```
DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, {:model => DatabaseA} ].strategy = :truncation
DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, {:model => DatabaseB} ].strategy = :truncation

Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

After do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

But it cleans only database connected by ActiveRecord::Base, not DatabaseA & DatabaseB
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this gist is exactly what you need: https://gist.github.com/1109325
Code looks weird, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works, but: 
1) Actually i want to use a bit different cleaning strategies for different databases (which is claimed to be supported in database_cleaner). in that script actually only last  
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
always wins, and i need to have different exeption for different databases.
2) it looks wierd, and non-DRY.  :)

Comment: As far as I remember, database_clearner supports different strategies only  for different ORM's (see http://goo.gl/JWMb8), therefore the only option for you is to fork database_cleaner and change its behavior.